# Is it possible to convert to a WAV file to AIFF in PHP, and viceversa?

Tags: php, audio, wav, aiff

I know it's possible to covert from AIFF and WAV to MP3, but in my project I need to have available all three formats (AIFF, WAV and MP3) from AIFF and WAV inputs. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php
    exec("ffmpeg -i file.wav -f aiff -ab 128000 -ar 44100 file.aif");
?>
```

Comment: here is what i use to go to WAV `ffmpeg -y -i file.mp3 -acodec pcm_s32le output.wav`

Answer (score 1):

Not elegant, but you can use underlying system tools to do it via `shell_exec()`

Comment: ffmpeg is a command line tool to can script to do the job

Comment: I can't find anything on AIFF conversion in [the doc](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html), am I missing something?

Comment: You may need a separate codec for AIFF, but it should be like `ffmpeg -i input_file -f aiff output_file`
You can list the available codecs with ffmpeg -formats

Comment: If a separate codec is needed, after you have installed it, add `-acodec codec_name` after `-f aiff`